# duplicate entries when logging nr of failed login attempts mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, security, logging

I have this set up to log the amount of failed login attempts from different ip addresses. Probably unnecessary complicated.

mysql db set up:

```
 CREATE TABLE login_attempts (
  id int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  ip varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `time` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  nr char(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
# -------
```

finding failed login attempts:

```
function ip()
{
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } 
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;            
}   

$ip = ip(); 
$query = "SELECT `nr` from `login_attempts` WHERE `ip`='".$ip."' ";
$result = $conn->query($query);         
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();     
$failed_attempts = $user["nr"];
```

(... some code ... )

If login fails:

```
    if( $failed_attempts == 0 ){

                $query = "INSERT INTO login_attempts (`ip`, `time`, `nr`) VALUES ('".$ip."', '".$time."', '1')";
                $result = $conn->query($query);             
                if (!$result){ trigger_error("mysql error: ".mysql_errno($result) . ": " . mysql_error($result)); return 0;  }

            } else {

                $query = "UPDATE login_attempts SET ip = '".$ip."', time = '".$time."', nr = nr + 1 "; 
                $result = $conn->query($query);             
                if (!$result){ trigger_error("mysql error: ".mysql_errno($result) . ": " . mysql_error($result)); return 0;  }

            }
```

This somehow gives duplicate entries in my db. Same ip, different `nr`.. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` query has no `WHERE` clause, so it updates **every row in the table**, setting the `ip` and `time` columns in all rows to those values.

```
$query = "UPDATE login_attempts SET time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, nr = nr + 1 WHERE ip = '$ip'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `WHERE` condition to the second SQL query. Otherwise it will update all rows in the table.